# Convert scientific notation number Xe+N to an integer in bash script

Tags: bash, scientific-notation

Given:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the number in scientific notation
my_number="2.2e+6"
```

I would like to convert this scientifically written notation number to an integer in my bash script. Right now, I use the following approach using Python within the Bash script to do it:

```
# Convert scientific notation to integer using Python
my_integer=$(python -c "print(int($my_number))")

echo "Original number: $my_number"
echo "As an integer: $my_integer" 

Original number: 2.2e+6
As an integer: 2200000
```

Is there a direct solution within bash script which I could use?

```
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
5.1.16(1)-release
```

And my Linux OS:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

### UPDATE:

As an alternative given in an accepted answer, I can do the following as well to save it into a variable `my_integer`:

```
my_integer=$(awk -v x="$my_number" 'BEGIN {printf("%d\n",x)}')
echo "my_integer: $my_integer" # 2200000
```

Comment: Is your format fixed, or do you have some flexibility?

Comment: "Cast" doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.  It appears that you want to _convert_ without changing the value.

Comment: Curious you have any trouble. https://ideone.com/xBbW4l runs in an Ubuntu 19.04 VM, and the printf approach works as-expected. I'm _almost_, but not quite, curious enough to install Docker to be able to try to repro in a real Ubuntu 22.04 environment...

Comment: Hmm. Actually I wonder if this could be a locale-specific problem; that would explain having a problem that doesn't easily reproduce elsewhere. If so, a different `LC_NUMERIC` setting might make the issue go away -- what does the `locale` command output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `awk` that would start faster than `python`:

```
awk -v x="$my_number" 'BEGIN {printf("%d\n",x)}'
```

Comment: how can I save it into a variable? this works in my terminal but not shell script!

Comment: Surround it with `$()`

Comment: Thanks, I did this to save it into a variable: `my_integer=$(awk -v x="$my_number" 'BEGIN {printf("%d\n",x)}')`

Comment: I would call this _exactly_ as direct / bash-native as Python is; they're both calling an interpreter for a non-bash language

Comment: Could also use `BEGIN {print 0 + x}` to coerce the value to a number

Comment: Agree, as bash-native as python, that's why I mentioned the start time, for example: `awk '{}' < /dev/null  0.00s user 0.00s system 90% cpu 0.001 total` vs `python -c "" < /dev/null  0.02s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.022 total`

Answer (score 4):

Just use `printf(1)` with an appropriate floating point conversion to not print anything after (or including) the decimal poin:

```bash
$ printf "%.0f\n" "2.2e+6"
2200000
```

or to save in a variable,

```bash
printf -v my_integer "%.0f" "2.2e+6"
```

Comment: in https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online, I can get `echo "$my_integer" 2200000` as an output but in my own machine, I get the value `2`. is there some problem in my bash version?

Comment: @doplano Without seeing what you're actually doing (Is there some way to share a session in jdoodle?), no idea.

Comment: I do this: #!/bin/bash

printf -v my_integer "%.0f" "2.2e+6"
echo "$my_integer"

Comment: @doplano That should display 2200000, yeah. What version of bash?

Comment: in my machine on the other hand, I get this error first: `printf: 2.2e+6: invalid number

Comment: `$ bash --version` returns: `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: `bash --version` is misleading -- it tells you which version is _first in the `PATH`_, not which version is _actually running_. `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` instead -- if it comes back empty you know your shell isn't actually bash at all.

Comment: Strange. The `-v variable-name` syntax isn't supported by every shell, but anything that follows POSIX even loosely should have a `printf` that understands floating point scientific notation. busybox, dash, sh, ksh, zsh, bash... all work as expected.

Comment: `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`returns `5.1.16(1)-release`

Comment: @doplano, ...silly question, but any chance your script might be saved with DOS newlines? A `$'\r'` character would make `2.2+e6` no longer read as a valid number, after all; running with xtrace (`LC_ALL=C bash -x yourscript`) should log in a way to make that or any other nonprintable-character-related problem clear. (If the `LC_ALL=C` makes the problem go away, then that guides us towards a different immediate cause).

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for your answer it works. It could be a problem on my local machine. in jdoodle it is correct.